# Spark SQL Expressions on UDT

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a UDT (User Defined Type).  I want to use it in Spark SQL expressions e.g. UDTName * 10.3.  My UDT is not just a simple number, it is a complex type that has its own overridden functions for +-/*.  I cannot achieve my desired logic with a standard scala type.

I tried using this in a Spark SQL expression in Spark 1.6.0 and got this result:

> cannot resolve '(UDTName * 10.0)' due to data type mismatch: differing types in '(udttype * 10.0)' (udttype and double).;

Is this operation supported in Spark?  Am I allowed to use UDTs in expressions?  Is there anything special I should do to tell Spark SQL that I have +-*/ operations available for this type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I allowed to use UDTs in expressions?

You are but it is definitely not as simple as that. Whenever you call `*` on in the expression you are using [a method defined on a `Column`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/4f11e3f2aa4f097ed66296fe72b5b5384924010c/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.scala#L657) which passes your data to arithmetic expression which is defined in [`org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-1.6/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/arithmetic.scala#L180). As you can expect these know nothing about your UDT.

In practice you can approach this problem at three different levels:

- Ignore expressions and use only an UDF to implement required operations. It is the simplest approach and all you need is just a couple of wrappers like:

  ```
  val complexMultiply = udf((x: ComplexNumber, y: Double) => x * y)
  ```
- create a custom expression (lets call it `ComplexMultiply`) which can be called by UDFs. You can check for example [Levenshtein distance implementation](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/7214/files) for details
- adjust your UDT and / or existing multiply implementation so it is properly handled by existing arithmetic expressions

Unless `*` is really a hard requirement I would probably stick with the first two.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  We have tried UDFs and they work very well.  Using expressions is very beneficial to the solution but we must take the level of effort into account.

Comment: "adjust your UDT and / or existing multiply implementation so it is properly handled by existing arithmetic expressions"  - This is what I was hoping to do.  Do you have a rough idea of what would be involved?

Comment: Truth be told I am not sure if it is worth all the fuss. While creating a custom expression is not particularly hard and you can easily handle this by example I am not exactly sure if getting `*` to work is possible without modifying built-in implementation and least for me it is a huge trade-off.

Comment: I plan to take a look at this when I'll have some spare time and I'll let you know if I figure something out.